# Append in <li><input/></li> works just one time

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to make a li inputable after the page being execute. I want the li function close to word office format. I mean, when we write on first list then ENTER it, it would focus on second list and ect. and this is my code I've made before:

```
<div class="writeform">
    <label class="subtitle">ingredients</label>
    <ol>
        <li><input class="formxyz globalwrite" id="ingred" name="ingred" placeholder="ingredients"></input>
        </li>

    </ol>
</div>
```

and this is the script in ajax

```
$('input#ingred').on('keydown',function(e){
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $('ol').append('<li><input class="formxyz globalwrite" id="ingred" name="ingred" placeholder="ingredients"></input></li>');
        $('input#ingred').focus();
    }
});
```

when I run this code, and write in the 1st line then I press ENTER, the second li shows up. But when I write in 2nd li and press enter, nothing appended. How can I make this append function work continously when I press ENTER key?

Comment: `$('input#ingred').on('keydown',function(e){` change to `$(document).on('keydown','input#ingred',function(e){` also use class instead of ID `input.ingred` or name like `'input[name=ingred]'` since you have name attribute already

Comment: i am sorry, actually i wrote my script inside $(document).ready(function() ... so, can this line of code put inside it? or maybe i should write it in same hierarchy of $(document).ready().., thank you

Comment: inside document . ready @ahr

Comment: wohoooo yes, it's work perfectly.. many many thank you @guradio

Comment: glad to help mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have duplicate uses of ID values - it is not valid HTML, and your selector for the input element would not work properly.  The same thing would be true with using a class, even though it is valid to have multiple uses of a class, the selection would select all matching elements.  You would need to generate a unique ID, or use a different selector to select the last input element, such as the jquery `.last()` selector.

Comment: this is missing event delegation

Answer (score 0):

If there are two ID selectors of the same name , jQuery only select the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the keydown event using delegation method, like this:

Change this:

`$('input#ingred').on('keydown',function(e) {`

Into this:

`$(document.body).on('keydown','input#ingred',function(e) {`

Because the first syntax will not bind to elements which are created later (dynamically).

**UPDATE**

For more correct way, you should make it bind to `class` or `name` attribute rather than `id`, because `id` id originally for naming elements and should be unique.

I think this is what you need in correct way: :D

`$(document.body).on('keydown','input.formxyz',function(e) {`

or:

`$(document.body).on('keydown','input[name="ingred"]',function(e) {`

Good luck!

Comment: thank you @taufik for your apply, i have tried with that code, but i stuck when i want to set the focus. :D... but any way, thank you very very much

Comment: @ahr you're very welcome! :D if you want to set focus to newly appended input, the you can do: `append(...).promise().done(function() { $('ol input[name="ingred"]:last').focus(); })`
sorry for late response, still working in my office as a programmer XD